# Comparing cells in two CSV files using powershell

Tags: powershell

Pretty new to this. I need to compare a column with usernames from one CSV file, against a column with usernames in another CSV file and output if duplicates exists or remove them.

How they currently look:

`$File1`:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Username
Peter,Larsen,Larsen.123
Pia,Jensen,Jensen.123
Poul,Hansen,Hansen.123
```

`$File2`:

```
Username
Larsen.123
Andersen.123
Jensen.123
```

What I'm looking for:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Username,Duplicate
Peter,Larsen,Larsen.123,True
Pia,Jensen,Jensen.123,True
Poul,Hansen,Hansen.123,False
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be a true/false output, removing all duplicate entries from File1 or similar, would be perfectly fine as well. It's essentially just to compare users in our AD against users in our user database, to see if anyone still have access who shouldn't have.

**Edit:**

Tried with this so far, found in a similar question in here:

```
foreach ($user in $File1) {
    $MatchAccount = (Compare-Object $File2 $user -Property 'Username' -PassThru).Value
    $user = Add-Member -InputObject $user -Type NoteProperty -Name 'Value' -Value $MatchAccount
```

And just importing and exporting the CSV files before and after, in that order.

Comment: What coding have you tried so far?  Welcome to Stackoverflow, please check the Help section for details about how to ask a solid question.  Your question is great except just needs details of your attempted code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the second file into a hashtable:

```
$users = @{}
Import-Csv 'file2.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $users[$_.Username] = $true
}
```

Then check if each row of the first CSV contains a username from that hashtable and [add a field](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) with the result of that check:

```
(Import-Csv 'file1.csv') |
    Select-Object *,@{n='Duplicate';e={$users.ContainsKey($_.Username)}} |
    Export-Csv 'file1.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach:

```
# import csv file1
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\tmp\file1.csv

# import csv file2 and select column "Username"
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path C:\tmp\file2.csv | % {$_.Username}

# create output/result hash table
$file3 = @()

# go through entries in file1
foreach($entry in $file1) {
    # check if entry is in not in file2
    if($file2 -notcontains $entry.Username) {
        # add entry to output hash table
        $file3 += $entry
    }
}

# export result to csv
$file3 | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\file3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`file3.csv` will then have the following contents

```
Firstname,Lastname,Username
Poul,Hansen,Hansen.123
```

Best regards
Guenther